Fundamental group of affine surface
Let $S=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{C}^3|x^5+y^5+z^5=1\}$. Then $S$ is a connected complex submanifold of complex dimension $2$. Is $S$ simply connected? Or how can one compute the fundamental group of $S$?
